# Reserving space for auto sized img

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want my image to have its width automatically sized (using image aspect ratio). I use something like:

```
img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

The problem is that until the image is loaded, the browser doesn't reserve horizontal space for it. Is there a way to make the browser reserve space for my image without using javascript?

I know the image aspect ratio as well as the height and width of the full size image.

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is a way to do this as long as you at least know the aspect ratio of the image(s).

The technique I have used successfully involves adding padding to a wrapper around the image based on the image's proportions. This technique was introduced (for video) by Thierry Koblentz and expanded upon (for images) by Anders M. Andersen.

```
<div class="grumpy-image-wrapper">
    <img class="grumpy-image" src="images/grumpy-cat.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="grumpy-image-wrapper">
    <img class="grumpy-image" src="images/grumpy-cat.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="grumpy-image-wrapper">
    <img class="grumpy-image" src="images/grumpy-cat.jpg" />
</div>

.grumpy-image-wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 66.67%; /* determined by image aspect ratio */
    border: 2px solid white;
    position: relative;
}
.grumpy-image {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Read more here: https://www.andyshora.com/css-image-container-padding-hack.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not from the front-end.  Until the image loads, the client-side doesn't know the dimensions of the image.  You could put a min-width on the img tag like this:

```
img{
    min-width: 100px /*or whatever you expect the 'default' width to do */
}
```

This will ensure that - at a minimum - that much space is 'reserved' for the image, but that will cause other issues if the site is responsive and would therefore need the image to potentially go smaller.

Your only real bet would be to grab the image dimensions at the back-end and pass the width/height attributes into the  tag like this:

```
<img src="xyz.jpg" width="100" height="50" >
```

Naturally those dimensions are only examples!  Again, this will limit you on the responsive-front, although you would also set the image via CSS so that it never over-flows the width of it's parent using:

```
img{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

If you're using PHP, you can get the image dimensions by using [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php), although this will add load to your server.

Comment: I know the dimensions of my image (from back-end). However, I want it to be resized dynamically depending on the dimensions of the containing block.

Comment: That shouldn't be too much of a problem.  You can use CSS to overwrite an image's dimension attributes, if you just want it to inherit it's width from the parent, you can set it to width: 100%;

Comment: @johnkavanagh, I don't see how it answers my question.

Comment: Xyand. The answer above will resolve the issue you're experiencing with images not occupying space in your large until loaded: if you're able to get the image dimensions from the backed, then using the width/height attributes on your image assure that. Additionally, you can use CSS to overwrite those dimensions, so using max-width: 100% will ensure the image confirms to the height of the contining block - as you mentioned in your last comment. Perhaps you could try it and then report back with a preview link if you're still struggling!

Comment: I just re-read my previous comment, it looks like I made a bit of an error there!  To confirm: if you use max-width: 100% it will ensure that the image conforms to the parent element's WIDTH (last comment I had put 'height').